# How can I round double values with E

Tags: swift, rounding

I have a number, like 4.99999999951e+001
I wish I could round this number like 5.000000000e+001
How can I manipulate the double value with out interfering the exponent part.

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code of what you have so far. Where are these values coming from? How are they going to be used/displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All double values have an exponent part. Don't get confused by any printout artifacts, especially from the debugger outputs.

`Double` has `round` and `rounded` methods, you can use them like this

```
let value = 4.99999999951e+001
let rounded = value.rounded() // or other modes, e.g. .rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this Extension for rounding Double values.

```
extension Double {
func roundTo(places: Int) -> Double {
    let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
    return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
}
```

Usage:

```
let v = 3.56789
v.roundTo(places: 1)
```

I use this in nearly every Project.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `round()` func

```
var x = 3.7
x.round()   output is // 4
```